# .net core and angular 7 project

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I am very new to .net core and angular project. I was given the application to create add and delete rows from the table using .net core and angular. I created the angular project inside the Visual studio application 2019. I didn't use the Visual studio code editor in order to create the angular project. I tested my controller after creating it and it was returning the data. When I run the application, I got an error saying

```
 Cannot GET /
```

My project structure is like this C:\ITProjects\ProjectsDetails. My angular project lies in 
c:\ITProjects\projectDetails\ClientApp

I compiled the entire application and ran the application by clicking on F5 and got the above error. Do I need to run the command ng serve in order to run the angular project or can I run the entire visual studio project by clicking on F5?
Below is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "ProjectDetails",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --extract-css",
    "build": "ng build --extract-css",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build -- --app=ssr --output-hashing=media",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0"
  }
}
```

any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't need to `ng serve` as long as the `MSBuild` `webpack` config hasn't been changed for that `.csproj`. I'd probably start there and see / understand how that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see something like this in the `MSBuild`:

```
<Target Name="DebugRunWebpack" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('wwwroot\dist') ">
    <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />

    <!-- In development, the dist files won't exist on the first run or when cloning to
         a different machine, so rebuild them if not already present. -->
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Performing first-run Webpack build..." />
    <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js" />
    <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js" />
</Target>

<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec Command="npm install" />
    <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod" />
    <Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod" />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="wwwroot\dist\**; ClientApp\dist\**" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

This is what will build your angular project and put it in the `wwwRoot` folder to be deployed so you don't have to `ng serve`.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer to keep my Angular and API projects separate while developing. You can use a proxy.config.json file to configure a proxy to solve cross domain requests. Then when you want to deploy you have a script to build the api, then build the Angular and copy the dist into the wwwroot folder of your api.